Network usage spikes when both wired and wireless active
I have an SSH tunnel active between two machines that we will call server and laptop.
server is permanently connected to my university's network.
laptop is normally connected to my university's network via a wireless connection, but sometimes I plug it into a docking station and connect it to the wired network as well.
I have noticed that when the network cable is plugged in the network usage increases massively, going from a few kbps to many Mbps. The CPU usage of the ssh process on my laptop that does the tunnelling also increases, reaching 5-10%.
What could be the cause? Are routes set up incorrectly?

What kind of SSH tunnel? What traffic does it carry? Is it a SOCKS tunnel or a tun interface? What traffic is routed through that interface, and what traffic do you see going through that interface?

Both, the ssh command has options -L port1:localhost:port2 -D port3. I don't think there is any traffic going through, just the pings from the ServerAliveInterval option.

So only a SOCKS tunnel at most, no tun; that could result in a loop but is a bit unlikely. You saw the "many Mbps" of traffic on the physical Ethernet interface, I assume? Run a packet capture on it to determine exactly what kind of traffic it was, whether it was SSH in the first place or something else.

@grawity_u1686 I have solved my problem; in the end the issue was unrelated to the tunnel: the university firewall for some reason leaves port 8080 open on the wired network, and I wasn't restricting ssh to listen only on localhost, so my laptop was getting random hostile connection attempts at a high pace. However your suggestion to run a packet capture helped me debug the problem. If you want to write it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.
